Visual Studio cannot load ccproj project with error "The path is not relative"
I have an ASP.NET solution (.NET framework). When I load it in VS 2022, all projects in the solution load fine except the .ccproj. When I try to reload it, I get

Error: the path is not relative

Does anyone know what it means, and how to resolve it?

Check the path it setting in the .sln file, right click on .sln (solution) file and open with notepad/notepad++ and see the path

In addition to @dawncode's answer its possible that you have cloned a few repo's into a different structure. So instead of changing the csproj path in the sln file, perhaps consider moving folders around to match what the solution file expects, this way if you check the repo in it won't stuff up the other contributors.

What is a ccproj file? Did you mean .csproj? Open the .sln file with Notepad and examine the contents.

Do you mean .csproj? Can you provide contents of the .sln file and your project directory structure?
Commonly, for the portability and version control purposes, using absolute paths instead of relative paths is not recommended in.csproj and .sln files.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/solutions-and-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-project-file-schema-reference?view=vs-2022
